# actionInvocation.invoke() is not calling the action instead gives the null pointer exception

Tags: java, struts2

I am a beginner in Java. I want to validate my session that without exixting session nobody would be able to login. I am doing this through interceptor and I have made the interceptor class in which if a session object is null and if session object is not equal to null then it would invoke the action but `actionInvocation.invoke()` is not working and it gives null pointer exception.

```
public class AuthenticationInterceptor implements Interceptor{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 

    public AuthenticationInterceptor() {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
    }

    @Override
    public String intercept(ActionInvocation actionInvocation) throws Exception {
        String vString=null;
      try{
            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) actionInvocation.getInvocationContext().get(StrutsStatics.HTTP_REQUEST);
             HttpSession session = request.getSession();
             System.out.println(session.getAttribute(Constant.CURRENT_USER));
             UserDTO userDTO=(UserDTO) session.getAttribute(Constant.CURRENT_USER);

        if(userDTO == null){
            System.out.println("userdto=null"+userDTO);
            vString = "login";
        }
        else if(!(userDTO).equals(null)){
                System.out.println("userdto!!!=null"+userDTO.getUserId());

                System.out.println("test...   "+actionInvocation.invoke());
                vString= actionInvocation.invoke();
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }return vString;

        }

    private void addActionError(Object action, String message) {
        if (action instanceof ValidationAware) {
            ((ValidationAware) action).addActionError(message);
        }
    }

}
```

below is the xml file ..

```
<interceptors>
            <interceptor name="authenticate" class="wm.com.erp.utility.AuthenticationInterceptor"/>

<interceptor-stack name="authenticateStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="authenticate"/>
            </interceptor-stack>
        </interceptors>

        <global-results>
            <result name="login" type="redirect">/index.jsp</result>
        </global-results>
<action name="Assignment" class="wm.com.erp.action.AssignmentAction" method="AssignmentList">
            <interceptor-ref name="authenticateStack"/>

            <result name="success">/Assignment.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">/home.jsp</result>
        </action>
```

Your help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow. Whenever you post regarding an error that you're getting, you should also post the stacktrace of it. Also, you should try to format your code ina way that makes it easy for us to read it (ie. remove any commented out code, blank spaces, irrelevant imports etc). Otherwise it's very hard for us to help you.

Comment: Add `defaultStack` to your interceptors stack.

Comment: yes ofcourse ..i will remember it next time..

Comment: also, remove the code that is not relevant to your question `addActionError`

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String,Object> session = invocation.getInvocationContext().getSession();

if(session.isEmpty())
      return Action.ERROR; // session is empty/expired error must be redirect on

return invocation.invoke();
```

tyr this code after this if you have problem then please post stack trace of your exception

Comment: @kapilDhunna If this is the answer that solved your problem you should mark it as the accepted one by clicking the accept mark under the vote count of the answer.